# Excel nested IF's

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-operator, countif

I have found several sites that talk about work arounds but they all talk about doing some kind of mathematical equation, so this is the nested if's I am trying to fix.

```
=IF((COUNTIF($A$137:$A$146,$C173)=1), 9203, IF((COUNTIF($A$161:$A$196,$C173)=1), 9202, IF((COUNTIF($A$199:$A$228,$C173)=1),9216, IF((COUNTIF($A$231:$A$255,$C173)=1),9222, IF((COUNTIF($A$258:$A$295,$C173)=1),9202, IF((COUNTIF($A$199:$A$228,$C173)=1),9216, IF((COUNTIF($A$298:$A$312,$C173)=1),9203, IF((COUNTIF($A$327:$A$361,$C173)=1),9202, IF((COUNTIF(A364:A383,$C173)=1),9219, Error)))))))))
```

Any tips?

Comment: The only obvious error is the use of the name 'Error' (without quotes). The word Error is seen here as a function, which is illegal. Try replacing it with quoted "Error". Alternatively, we will need more detail to go on...

Comment: As you've been a member of Stack Overflow for more than a month, never voted, never answered a question, and never accepted an anwer, let me post my welcome message (see below)

Comment: HuX, when editing a cell formula, you can use alt+enter to trigger a page break.  This can be very useful for debugging your code and making it easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the last word **Error**. It's not a valid name in Excel. Replace for example with **"Error"**

Comment: @Kevin You posted your observation as a comment while I was elaborating my answer. So far, so good, but when you decide to post something as a comment it's just because you understand it's not an answer, or you are not sure about it, so you're not exposing neither to downvotes nor upvotes. Anyway, I saw your posting after posting mine.

Comment: You are correct, and no harm done.  I actually just expected the problem might be something more elaborate.  Perhaps not afterall.

Comment: @Kevin Me too. That's why I actually reviewed all those nested IFs and parens (a rather unpleasant job, I might say) :D

Comment: The problem isn't the Error... Excel doesn't allow over 7 nested if's so I need to find an alternate way

Comment: @Huxu7 that is version dependent. What version are you working on?